# How to find the main part in substring using neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm in a big confuse. Is it possible to find whe main word or substring (with the help of training set) in sentence. I'm parsing vacancies and trying to build a text-maining app, that could quess what skills are mentioned in the text. Yes, maybe this is task for some kind of global text search with skill's dictionary, but i'm really very curious, can NN help?
As you have guesed, I'm a newbie at ML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word2Vec is a basic application of Neural Networks that could help create a numerical representation of words, which you could use to build a smart interpretation of your sentences.

More interestingly, using a LSTM can handle context, and identify key words in sentences like in this paper: http://www.clsp.jhu.edu/~guoguo/papers/icassp2015_myhotword.pdf .  This is a paper on identifying key words in sentences to allow for faster, more useful applications of voice recognition software.  Here is the github: https://github.com/MajerMartin/lstm-dtw-keyword-spotting .   It's too much to explain in this post but that should keep you busy and get you started training a neural network for keyword identification.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No NNs cannot help.

Long answer: Maybe they can if you really, REALLY want them to and have tons of time and skill.
The Problem is that Neural Networks are used to handle numbers and not words.
Most types of Neural Networks rely on the capability to decide if two values are close to each other. This is still not easy with strings in a language context.

So if you don't want to spend the next few years researching Neural Networks I would look for a different approach ;)

Comment: Btw there are some really cool Projects using Neural Networks and Strings/Language. Take this for example:
http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0140866

But as I said, they are really complicated and take lots of time.

Comment: Huh, but what is better approach in machine learning? I know about hardcoded rules in NLP, but it is a bit complicated, because my natural lang is russian

Comment: The answer of Rob seems interesting. Hmm Russian? Yeah either NLP or you might be able to extract skills based on how they are written.
Like, are skills always nouns? Can one identify them easily in Russian.
Personally I would use what you allready suggested (Dictionary of skills) or use Robs answer

Comment: Well, they are not always nouns, especially soft-skills